# How to find datacontext of parent's parent for dynamic control

Tags: wpf, xaml, contextmenu, datacontext

We have following xaml code to display context menu and fire command when delete menu is clicked.
For the context menu item, I would like to bind command which is present in DataContext of ItemsControl. We tried with `RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}` but as the tree is created dynamically (using dataContext) it is not able to find DeleteCommand.

```
<Grid x:Name="MyGrid" >
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TreeRoot.Children}">
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
          <StackPanel>
            <Label Background="Black"  Content="{Binding Path=DisplayText}"/>
            <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource myCompositeNodeConverter}}" >
              <TreeView.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:CompositeNode}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}" >
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DisplayText}" Foreground="Black"></TextBlock>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:LeafNode}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DisplayText}"></TextBlock>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
              </TreeView.Resources>
              <TreeView.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu >
                  <MenuItem Header="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" />
                </ContextMenu>
              </TreeView.ContextMenu>
            </TreeView>
          </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
  </Grid>
```

How do we bind DeleteCommand for context menu item to DataContext of ItemsControl?